# Stop method execution

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a class that tries to get information from web service few times:

```
public TResult Try(Func<TResult> func, int maxRetries)
{
    TResult returnValue = default(TResult);
    int numTries = 0;
    bool succeeded = false;

    while (numTries < maxRetries)
    {
        try
        {
            returnValue = func();
            succeeded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex,numTries);
        }
        finally
        {
            numTries++;
        }
        if (succeeded)
        {
            return returnValue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (numTries == maxRetries)
            {
                 //ask user what to do
            }
        }
  }
```

Now after 'if (numTries == maxRetries)' user will be able to chose if he wants to continue trying to get data from web service or cancel.
I want to just open new form when user cancels and stop executing method that called above method. I can't just return null or new object because the method that run this retrier will continue to work and in many cases cause problems.

So basically this looks like this:

```
someValue = retry.Try(() => webService.method(),maxRetries));
//if user canceled after app wasn't able to get data stop execution as already another form is opened
```

I could of course check if returned value was null like:

```
someValue = retry.Try(()=>webService.method(),maxRetries));
if (someValue == null) 
return;
```

But this would mean a lot of changes in the code and I want to avoid it and it would be best if I could do it from Try method.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things.  You could make sure that `TResult` is of an Interface type that has a `Boolean` field that represents a successful request (IsSuccessful or IsValid, etc).  If you cannot modify `TResult`, the other option is to use an `Out` parameter on your try method to pass another value out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to just stop the execution of a method. The first thing that comes to mind though is to throw an exception and catch it from the calling method.

Keep in mind though that you shouldn't ever rely on exceptions to control flow like that.. but if you **really** can't rewrite the calling method, this may be your only option.

The other option is perhaps having your returned result set a flag (via an interface) to notify the caller that it completed successfully.